# Providing non-interactive, programmatic inputs to shell scripts

Tags: rpm, gnupg

I have to trigger a RPM command from JAVA. The command looks like this.

```
rpm -addsign apc.rpm
```

This RPM, internally calls GPG. The GPG would require a password, which it eventually passes back to RPM and RPM throws the control back to the user on the command line, waiting for a password. I don't want the user to enter that password. I want to somehow supply that password to the RPM, so that the user doesn't need to do anything other than simply running the JAVA program. Supplying the password like the below way is not helping.

```
rpm -addsign abc.rpm -passwd
```

Since this password is not something that RPM uses, but is simply throwing whatever GPG is asking for, the above mentioned way will not work. Is there a way in which a file can be given as an input for the subsequent questions being asked for?

How could I make this possible? Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: You can use something like `expect` to provide the password when `rpm` asks for it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the password *IS* something that rpm reads and passes to gpg.

The issue is in getpass(3) to read the password which reopens /dev/tty
in order to turn off echoing etc.

So you need to attach a pseudo-tty (which will permit passing input
as if it came from a keyboard) to /dev/tty before invoking rpm --addsign.

Short answer: Use expect (which will do the hard work of creating/attaching
a pseudo-tty to /dev/tty).